# I get ''execution fail: cat << EOT | /var/tmp/one/vmm/kvm/deploy '/var/lib/one//datastores/101/103/deployment.0' " Permission denied

Tags: qemu, libvirt, opennebula

I'm creating a new VM and get this ***error***. What should I do?

> Mon Jan 21 13:06:41 2019 [Z0][ReM][D]: Req:2080 UID:0 one.vmpool.info
>   invoked , -2, 0, -200, -1 Mon Jan 21 13:06:41 2019 [Z0][ReM][D]:
>   Req:2080 UID:0 one.vmpool.info result SUCCESS,
>   "69<..." Mon Jan 21 13:06:41 2019 [Z0][ReM][D]:
>   Req:8720 UID:0 one.user.info invoked , 0 Mon Jan 21 13:06:41 2019
>   [Z0][ReM][D]: Req:8720 UID:0 one.user.info result SUCCESS,
>   "0
>
> Mon Jan 21 13:06:43 2019 [Z0][VMM][D]: Message received: LOG I 103
>   Successfully execute network driver operation: pre.
>
> Mon Jan 21 13:06:44 2019 [Z0][VMM][D]: Message received: LOG I 103
>   Command execution fail: cat << EOT | /var/tmp/one/vmm/kvm/deploy
>   '/var/lib/one//datastores/101/103/deployment.0'
>   'fast.sense.dcc.ufmg.br' 103 fast.sense.dcc.ufmg.br
>
> Mon Jan 21 13:06:44 2019 [Z0][VMM][D]: Message received: LOG I 103
>   error: Failed to create domain from
>   /var/lib/one//datastores/101/103/deployment.0
>
> Mon Jan 21 13:06:44 2019 [Z0][VMM][D]: Message received: LOG I 103
>   error: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor:
>   2019-01-21T15:06:44.029263Z qemu-system-x86_64: -drive
>   file=/var/lib/one//datastores/101/103/disk.1,format=qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,cache=none:
>   Could not open '/var/lib/one//datastores/101/103/disk.1': Permission
>   denied
>
> Mon Jan 21 13:06:44 2019 [Z0][VMM][D]: Message received: LOG E 103
>   Could not create domain from
>   /var/lib/one//datastores/101/103/deployment.0
>
> Mon Jan 21 13:06:44 2019 [Z0][VMM][D]: Message received: LOG I 103
>   ExitCode: 255
>
> Mon Jan 21 13:06:44 2019 [Z0][VMM][D]: Message received: LOG I 103
>   Failed to execute virtualization driver operation: deploy.
>
> Mon Jan 21 13:06:44 2019 [Z0][VMM][D]: Message received: DEPLOY
>   FAILURE 103 Could not create domain from
>   /var/lib/one//datastores/101/103/deployment.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved!
I added oneadmin to sudo group:

```
sudo adduser oneadmin sudo
```

And, added:

```
user = "root"
group = "root"
dynamic_ownership = 0
```

to /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf

Answer (score 0):

Installing the [opennebula-node-kvm](https://docs.opennebula.io/5.12/deployment/node_installation/kvm_node_installation.html) package on the VM host server would take care of all of this i.e

- creating ****oneadmin** user**,
- defining required **sudo privileges** to oneadmin user
- creating the **/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf** with the required configuration

  user = "root"
  group = "root"
  dynamic_ownership = 0

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this directory `/var/lib/one/` needs to be owned by **oneadmin**.

You don't need to add **oneadmin** users to the **sudo** group.

Just make sure that the `/var/lib/one/` directory is owned by **oneadmin**, and you are ready to go.

You can check the ownership of the `/var/lib/one/` directory with the following command:

```
ls -ld /var/lib/one/
drwxr-x--- 8 oneadmin oneadmin 253 Jan 12 2023 /var/lib/one/
```